# Having problems with a expanding Java Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently doing an Array in Java that requires for the user to input a number which leads to an expanding array without the use of a conditional loop like if...else or switch. For example:
If user entered 2:
Output : 2 2 2
2 1 2
2 2 2

or if user entered 3:
Output: 3 3 3 3 3
3 2 2 2 3
3 2 1 2 3
3 2 2 2 3
3 3 3 3 3

This is what I have gotten so far but it breaks the rule of no conditional if...else.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int choice;
        String space= " ";
        System.out.println("Please Enter an input : ");
        choice=input.nextInt();
        int adapt[];
        int num=choice;
        int increment=choice-1;
        
        
        if(choice==2)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<=choice; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<choice-increment; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(space + (choice) + space);
                }

                for(int j=choice-increment; j<choice; j++)
                {
                    if(i==choice-increment) 
                    {
                        System.out.print(space + (choice-increment) + space);
                    }
                    else
                    System.out.print(space + (choice) + space);
                }

                for(int j=choice-increment; j<choice; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(space + (choice) + space);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrasing of the question is confusing. Inspecting your code it looks like you are trying to draw a square grid of integers, where the digits increment radially from the central digit (1) in the middle of the grid. This is a typical programming question which is designed to teach you about loops and indices. Thus your question is really not Java related, however I have given you a working solution in Java below.

Conditional statements are not necessary to solve this problem. The only language construct required is a for loop, specifically a double-nested for loop since this is a two-dimensional problem.

```
public class Grid {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter an input : ");
    final int p = input.nextInt();
    // square grid with side length 2p + 1
    final int[][] grid = initGrid(2 * p + 1);
    fillGrid(grid, p);
    printGrid(grid);
  }

  private static int[][] initGrid(int size) {
    // 2-d int array
    int[][] grid = new int[size][];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      grid[i] = new int[size];
    }
    return grid;
  }

  private static void fillGrid(int[][] grid, int p) {
    for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
        grid[row][col] = calculateValue(row, col, p);
      }
    }
  }

  private static int calculateValue(int row, int col, int centre) {
    // the algorithm for calculating the value of the cell
    int dx = Math.abs(row - centre);
    int dy = Math.abs(col - centre);
    return 1 + Math.max(dx, dy);
  }

  private static void printGrid(int[][] grid) {
    for (final int[] row : grid) {
      for (int cell : row) {
        System.out.print(String.format(" %2d ", cell));
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```